# What is the meaning of "ищущим людям" in this text?

Tags: значения, выражения

The context is the following paragraph (from https://baaltii1.livejournal.com/198675.html):

> Этот разговор мы начали в Принстоне, прогуливаясь по тамошней жизни и красивому закату. Показалось, что подобный разговор может быть интересен многим: и математикам, и просто **ищущим людям**. Итак, вопросы задает Рома Михайлов. Отвечает Владимир Воеводский.

Going by individual words and some research on the web (e.g, [1]), it seems that it could be translated as "seekers", meaning individuals actively looking for (deep) truths in life.

Is this correct? What do you think?

[1] https://vladimirdovgan.livejournal.com/135706.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, "seeker" is exactly what it means.

> - Основная проблема, перед которой стоял ищущий человек, была вполне ясна – религия и атеизм // The main problem a seeker was facing, was very clear: religion or atheism.
> - Любой спортсмен – это ищущий человек, который стремится стать быстрее, выше, сильнее // Any athlete is a seeker, aiming to become faster, higher, stronger
> - Ради поиска этой красоты, ради своего зрителя ищущий человек может преодолеть всё // A seeker can overcome anything for the search of this beauty, for their audience

Answer (score 2):

The `Ищущий` in this case has a non-specific meaning, but rather poetic.
May indicate:

- person interested in math;
- person interested in self-development, broadening the horizons